# Ballistics of guns

Tags: reference-request, classical-mechanics

I am looking for mathematical texts or material on ballistics of guns. So far the only reference I have been able to locate is Ballistics: Theory and Design of Guns and Ammunition  by Carlucci and Jacobson. Are there any more such books or online notes which explain the mathematical properties (equation of motion etc) in gun ballistics?

Comment: You might try books on forensics, forensic science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a steep learning curve in ballistics. The start is to assume only Newton's Laws and no air resistance, etc. The next is to include air resistance, which is incorporated in this [assignment](http://www.brookscole.com/math_d/special_features/stewart_shared/mathematica_labs/08-differentialequations/p04a.pdf). Then, it can become radically more complicated. For example, JSTOR has several articles on ballistics (e.g. [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/91246)), so if you have access I would look there.

These end up relying on a good working knowledge of PDE and fluid dynamics, so I'm not quite sure if those are what you're looking for. But there are also programs that do a lot of this work for you if you are just calculating them: you have [gunsim](http://gunsim.com/) and it's [blog](http://www.gun-blog.com/), for example. Someone else also describes the math that they use in their own sim, found [here](http://www.telusplanet.net/public/prescotj/data/archery/ballcalcs.html).

I do not know of any other 'texts' so to speak, only lots of articles. Once you look through JSTOR, you can look at their references and what referenced them to continue on the chain. I hope this is what you're looking for!

(Note, if you have access to a university library, you might have access to JSTOR articles through them).

Answer (score 1):

Nonsense.  Ballistics maths is very well understood and incredibly easy.  Certainly a knowledge of the basic Newtonian physics is a good background but the mathematics itself is basic numerical integration in most cases, based on the work of one Fransesco Siacci.  The definitive book today that most professional ballisticians use for small arms ballistics is "Modern Exterior Ballistics" by Robert McCoy.  He worked at the Ballistics Research Laboratory Aberdeen Proving ground for a number of years and he gives a comprehensive history of the subject.
The book also includes the listing of a BASIC program for Point Mass Model approximation (the most widely adopted modern adaptation of Siacci's formulae) and that basic program itself (including source code) can be found on several locations on the www - just search for "MCTRAJ".